# An inequality including Suprema & Minima of a function f.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function defined on an interval $[a,b]$, let $S$ be a subset of $[a,b]$, we need to prove that:

$$M( |f| ,S ) - m( |f| ,S )\le M( f ,S ) - m( f ,S ).$$

What I tried: For any $x\in [a,b]$, $|f(x)|\ge f(x)$,
So, $m|f(x)|\ge mf(x)$ or $m(|f|,S)\ge m(f,S)$ so, $-m(|f|,S)\le -m(f,S)$;
Now, the supremum of $|f|$ and $f$ must be equal for any $x\in[a,b]$, 
Thus add $M( f ,S )$ on both sides and we get: 
$$M( |f| ,S ) - m( |f| ,S )\le M( f ,S ) - m( f ,S )$$ as $M( |f| ,S )$ must be equal to $M( f ,S )$.
Is the above proof correct ??

$M$ and $m$ are the supremum and infimum respectively.

Is the above proof correct ??

Comment: Shouldn't it be infimum instead of supremum troughout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach:

The triangle inequality gives
$|f(x)|-|f(y)| \le |f(x)-f(y)|$.

This is true for all $x,y$, so we have
$|f(x)|-|f(y)| \le \sup_{x',y' \in S} |f(x')-f(y')|$.

Note that $\sup_{x',y' \in S} |f(x')-f(y')|= \sup_{x',y' \in S} (f(x')-f(y')) = \sup_{x' \in S} f(x') - \inf_{y' \in S} f(y')$, so we have 
$|f(x)|-|f(y)| \le \sup_{x' \in S} f(x') - \inf_{y' \in S} f(y')$, for all $x,y \in S$.

Hence $\sup_{x,y \in S} (|f(x)|-|f(y)|) \le \sup_{x' \in S} f(x') - \inf_{y' \in S} f(y')$.

Since we have 
$\sup_{x,y \in S} (|f(x)|-|f(y)|) = \sup_{x \in S} |f(x)|-\inf_{y \in S} |f(y)|$, we have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'd show the following:

- If $\inf f\ge 0$, then $\sup |f|=\sup f$ and $\inf |f|=\inf f$, so the claim holds (with equality)
- If $\sup f\le 0$, then $\sup|f|=-\inf f$ and $\inf|f|=-\sup f$, so agaon the claim holds (with equality)
- Remains the case $\inf f <0<\sup f$. Then $\sup|f|=\max\{\sup f,-\inf f\}$ and $\inf |f|\ge 0$. Then $\sup |f|-\inf|f|\le \sup |f|=\max\{\sup f,-\inf f\}$. As for $u<0<v$ we always have $\max\{u,-v\}<u-v$ (this is in fact the triangle inequality!), the claim follows